# Make a specific cell editable based on checkbox JTable

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

I have a JTable with 7 columns in which the 6th is a boolean (checkbox). I would like to make the 7th column's cell become editable only when the boolean in the 6th column is checked. For example, if (2,6) is checked, I would like ONLY (2,7) to become editable.

The following code makes the entire row editable (*but I want cell to the right of boolean only*):

```
@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
    if (col == 5)   // 0-indexed (6th col)
        return true;
    else
        return ((Boolean) getValueAt(row, 5)).booleanValue();
}
```

*Afterwards, I would like a way to quickly get all the checked rows so I can get the value of the 7th column for each row.*

---

**Update** w/ Guido's input: The code works, but I get NullPointerException when I click on non-editable cells of the 7th column (regardless of if one set to be editable or not).

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ManagerDisplay$1.isCellEditable(ManagerDisplay.java:82)
    at javax.swing.JTable.editCellAt(JTable.java:3500)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just need this:

```
@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
    if (col == 5)   // 0-indexed (6th col)
        return true;
    else if (col == 6) // 7th col
        return ((Boolean) getValueAt(row, 5)).booleanValue();
    else                // every other column
        return false; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked as expected! When I click the non-editable (7th) columns, I get NullPointerException, Full Error has been added to original post.

Comment: @Ali: that is a new problem, and rather than present shifting requirements to confound all of us, you should accept Guido's answer, up-vote it, and then ask a new question for your new problem.

Comment: @Ali: Also for your next question know that the most important bit of information that we need is the exception's associated stacktrace and some identification of the line that causes it, something that the stacktrace will tell you. In other words -- you must show the offending code, something that you're not doing, but again, don't show it here -- ask a new question and show it there.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Should I wait for the solution to getting all the checked rows or should that be done in another question as well?

Comment: @Ali the question about collecting all the rows values would deserve it's own post as well, but, as it stands, it would probably be closed as too broad or unclear; you will need to provide details on what you then want to do with the collected values, and some code snippets to clarify the context.